# combine multiple strings into one textarea

Tags: php, string, textarea

Can someone tell me how can I make this code under one textarea. I'm fairly new to php so any bit of advice would be helpful thanks.

```
if ($test != "")
  print("<p>" . format_comment($test) . "</p>\n");
if ($test1 != "")
  print("<p>" . format_comment($test1) . "</p>\n");
```

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean "make this code" and "under one textarea"? 

Something like `print("<textarea>$test\n$test1</textarea>");`?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to achieve, try it like this:

```
// Print the top
print("<p><hr>");

// Print $text if set
if ($test != "")
  print(format_comment($test));

// Print $text1 if set
if ($test1 != "")
  print(format_comment($test1));

// Print the bottom
print("<hr></p><br />");
```

Altough, I recommend you to use `echo` instead of `print`, because `echo` is a more common used function. Using `echo` you can do it like this:

```
echo "<p><hr>";
if ($test != "")
  echo format_comment($test);
if ($test1 != "")
  echo format_comment($test1);
echo "<hr></p><br />";
```

I might understood your question wrong, if you just want to put the content from the variables into a text area, you can do it as follows:

```
$content = "";
if ($test != "")
  $content .= "<p><hr>" . format_comment($test) . "<hr></p><br />";
if ($test1 != "")
  $content .= "<p><hr>" . format_comment($test1) . "<hr></p><br />";
echo "<textarea>" . $content . "</textarea>";
```

**EDIT:** It looks like you've used `\n` to get a new line, you should use `<br />` instead in HTML. Simply replace all the `\n`parts with `<br />` to fix the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first code you gave works but the two $test and $test1 end up on one line. Is it possible to make it so they can end up one under another?

Comment: Yes, you have used `\n` to get a new line I think, you should use `<br />` instead, so simply replace those `\n` parts with `<br />`, thats all. I'm glad it works!

Comment: Can you tell me where I can put the <br /> code. Because I get a lot of errors...

Comment: in the textarea I get this: <p><hr>$test<hr></p><br /><p><hr>test1<hr></p><br />

Comment: technically I have 2 files temp.php and formm.php. When I type something in the websitename.com/temp.php I want it to be send to websitename.com/formm.php in a textarea box. Hare are the pastebins of both: http://pastebin.com/kBMA5MA9 http://pastebin.com/PP66dnaL

Comment: I'm aiming for this effect: http://oi42.tinypic.com/ipv1co.jpg to http://oi43.tinypic.com/111m9tx.jpg

Comment: You should make a HTML <form> of your inputs, then the data could be send using the POST method to the formm.php page, on that page, you should retrieve the data send using POST and you should put it into the textbox. You can search on google for a lot of examples using forms and POST methods. You should search for something like: 'PHP Post', for example this one:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: The files are working properly I just need to know how can I make them  into textarea box. or if there is a way to add a table for if ($test != "")
  print("<p>" . format_comment($test) . "</p>\n");
if ($test1 != "")
  print("<p>" . format_comment($test1) . "</p>\n"); then maybe the textarea box code can be added?

Answer (score 0):

You may try by concatenating both content

```
<?php
require "include/bittorrent.php";
dbconn(); 


stdhead("Tags");
begin_main_frame();
begin_frame("Tags");
$test = $_POST["test"];
$test1 = $_POST["test1"];

    $content="<p><hr>";

    if ($test != "")
      $content .= format_comment($test);
    if ($test1 != "")
      $content .= format_comment($test1);

    $content=$content. "<hr></p><br />";
?>

 <textarea id="test" name="test"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>


<?php 

end_frame();
end_main_frame();
stdfoot();
?>
```

Comment: sorry for the reply I'm new to this website xD

Comment: i haven't see what you were doing when i was in edit ..let me see..you don't need print to create it ..you can try the way i have made..if your problem is solved by this then you may choose it as right ans :)

Comment: it gives me Parse error: parse error, unexpected '<' on line 2

Comment: @nidal khalaf i added <br /> you can check it.

Comment: there is still unexpected '<' on line 2, here is the code from pastebin http://pastebin.com/PP66dnaL

Comment: @nidalkhalaf khalaf i checked but this not having any issue you have other functions and what values you sending in $_POST["test1"] and $_POST["test"]

Comment: technically I have 2 files temp.php and formm.php. When I type something in the websitename.com/temp.php I want it to be send to websitename.com/formm.php in a textarea box. Hare are the pastebins of both: http://pastebin.com/kBMA5MA9 http://pastebin.com/PP66dnaL

Comment: did your temp.php have  <?php tag in the starting also you don't need <? in the end of form in temp.php

Comment: argh, sorry about that, refresh the pastebin urls, I've edited them

Comment: I'm aiming for this effect: http://oi42.tinypic.com/ipv1co.jpg to http://oi43.tinypic.com/111m9tx.jpg

Comment: no issues found in the files but i cannot find the issue as you have some functions with you and also can you tell me which page you seeing the error and triggering what event..

Comment: the files work properly no errors there. the thing is that I want to make the final resoult in a textarea box shown in the pictures I've posted.

Comment: do you have any dummy working url i can see it,also you told unexpected '<'  error showing. this showing in which page and after what event...

Comment: you are replacing with my code that is okay but do you adding any extra php tag that is causing the error.can you show me your updated code after adding my code..

Comment: After `</textarea>` end you need to add a `<?php` tag.Can you add and check it

Comment: still not functioning properly. in the textarea it gives me: <p><hr>31<hr></p><br /> you can also check it

Comment: @nidal khalaf it is upto you how you want to wrap your content.you can use `p` or `div` or `table`.so now you not seeing any error and you got the content inside `textarea`.now can you upload this two file in a dummy sever and show me what is happening and how you want.

Comment: is it possible to make a table code for if ($test != "")
  print("<p>" . format_comment($test) . "</p>\n");
if ($test1 != "")
  print("<p>" . format_comment($test1) . "</p>\n"); and in the table code to add the textarea code?